# Realm objective-c change schema from float to double

Tags: objective-c, realm

I want to update one property from `float` to `double` however there are no specific documentation at all about this type of migration.

Is it easy by just changing the property type in the class?
Is there some difficulty with the changing? (How?)
Or is not available at all?

Although My requirement is not that strict in the case that we can wipe that data column out or even clear all the rows of that class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy.

Say your first schema version looks like this:

```
// Models
class MyModel: Object {
  dynamic var prop: Float = 0
}

// Usage
let configuration = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 0)
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
```

Then you change the property from float to double, bump the schema version, and convert the floats from the old objects to doubles on the new object:

```
// Models
class MyModel: Object {
  dynamic var prop: Double = 0
}

// Usage
let configuration = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 1, migrationBlock: { migration, _ in
  migration.enumerate(MyModel.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
    newObject!["prop"] = Double(oldObject!["prop"] as! Float)
  }
})
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
```

This is all documented in [Realm's Migration docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations).

Comment: Thanks, I also notice when I am trying to just only change the type. Realm display the error something like saying `float type is not convert to double type` and wipe all the data in db to create a new one. and with that useful error I can come up with a way to just add the migration block and all is fine!

Answer (score 0):

Change your property type from float to double and run

```
RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];

    config.migrationBlock = ^(RLMMigration *migration, uint64_t oldSchemaVersion) {

        if(oldSchemaVersion < 26) {
            [migration enumerateObjects:TransformationParameters.className block:^(RLMObject * _Nullable oldObject, RLMObject * _Nullable newObject) {
                newObject[@"translationX"] = @([oldObject[@"translationX"] doubleValue]);

            }];
        }
    };
```

This performs the conversion from float to double by the call to `doubleValue`